# How to tell cvxpy how to sum over values of a matrix in an objective function?

Tags: python, optimization, gradient-descent, convex-optimization, cvxpy

I want to implement this optimization problem from [this paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7978-generative-modeling-for-protein-structures.pdf) using cvxpy or any similar library.
The problem I am facing is how do I code this so it is understandable for cvxpy.

[image: Objective function]

```
from cvxpy import *
g = Variable(n)
eta = Variable(n)
loss = sum(g+g-(2*g)+eta-(d**2))
reg = norm(eta, 1)
lambd = Parameter(nonneg=True)
prob = Problem(Minimize(lambd*reg+0.5*loss))
```

I know my definition of loss is obviously incorrect, I just had to put something to illustrate my problem. I don't know how to tell cvxpy to treat indices of the matrices the way I want them. Is this even possible in cvxpy? Is there any other library that could do this easily? Any code sample will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can construct the cost function in a loop. It also seems that `g` should be positive semidefinite, so I added `PSD=True`. Here's a complete example:

```
from cvxpy import *
n = 10
g = Variable((n, n), PSD=True)
eta = Variable((n, n))
reg = norm(eta, 1)
d = np.ones((n, n))
lamb = 1.

cost = 0
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        cost += (g[i, i] + g[j, j] - 2 * g[i, j] + eta[i, j] - d[i, j]**2) ** 2

cost = 0.5 * cost + lamb * reg
prob = Problem(Minimize(cost))
prob.solve()
```