# How to implement loop in Quadratic programming using cvxpy

Tags: optimization, cvxpy, quadratic-programming

I want to know whether cvxpy can only implement this form of quadratic programming (just one formulation):

`objective = cp.Minimize(cp.sum_squares(A @ x - b))`

This is the link in cvxpy to implement Mixed-integer quadratic program:
https://www.cvxpy.org/examples/basic/mixed_integer_quadratic_program.html

If I want to solve an objective function of the sum form：
[image]

Whether I can use a nested **for** loop to implement it? But I don't know how to do and I can not find the API to implement it. I used to implement Linear programming using Python library PULP, and it can use **for** loop to define the objective function and the constraints. Can i do this in cvxpy library？

Is my expression clear? If you need more information, just contact me. Thank you!

Comment: If A,D are your variables then this does not look like a convex problem at all.

Comment: Just A is variables, and D is known.

Comment: Is this a convex problem?

Comment: No. Something like ``(log(a1)-log(a2)+c)^2`` is not a convex function of ``a1,a2``.

Comment: Why it is not a convex function? It means that it can not be solved,right?

Comment: Then what about (x1/x2+c)^2?

Comment: Nonconvexity of your functions can be checked by making a plot, often restricting to one variable is enough. You can maybe solve those problems with a general nonlinear solver. Or maybe you should reformulate it somehow. From the little context you provided all I can say is that the function you wrote is not convex.

Comment: Thank you. I also want to know whether I can use `for` loop to implement ∑ using cvxpy.

Comment: There is an example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53900394/9332433

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249904/discussion-between-happy-and-michal-adamaszek).